# Three div in row and text of div break line when text exceeds div limits

Tags: html, css

I am using `white-space: nowrap;` in parent div which is sticking it's child div's in a row.

In the child div's I use `word-wrap: break-word;` which is not working inside of `white-space:nowrap;`.

My expected result is that all divs in a row even they reach screen limit but when div text exceed div width limit text line break to next line.

[Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/tdc300up/)

```html
<div overflow-x:auto; width="100%" style="white-space: nowrap">
  <div style="display: inline-block; width: 200px; border-right: solid #778899">

    <div style="padding: 0 10px; background-color: white; height: 130px; overflow-x: hidden;">
      div1
      <p class="text-center" style="word-wrap: break-word;">
        datasssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss

      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="width:200px; display: inline-block; border-right: solid #778899;">

    <div class="pd-5" style="background-color: white; height: 130px; overflow-x: hidden;">

      div2
      <p class="text-center" style="word-wrap: break-word;">
        ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss ssssssss
      </p>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="width: 200px; display: inline-block; border-right: solid #778899;">

    <div class="pd-5" style="background-color: white; height: 130px; overflow-x: hidden;">

      div3
      <p class="text-center" style="word-wrap: break-word;">
        sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss
      </p>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `white-space:pre-wrap;`.

Here's an updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tdc300up/1/

Here's the CSS code I used to solve it:

```
div > div > div { 
   white-space: pre-wrap;      /* CSS3 */   
   white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Firefox */    
   white-space: -pre-wrap;     /* Opera <7 */   
   white-space: -o-pre-wrap;   /* Opera 7 */    
   word-wrap: break-word;      /* IE */
}
```

Alternatively, you could also use

```
div { 
   white-space: normal;
}
```

as show in this fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/tdc300up/3/

*(take note that you don't need all of the additional pre-fixes here thanks to better support - see [https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/whitespace/#browser-support)](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/whitespace/#browser-support)_)*

**Edit**

As mentioned by WorkWe in the comments, another fix that you could try is removing the `white-space:nowrap;` from the main parent container (if it is not required for something else).

You can see an example fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/tdc300up/4/

Comment: For your mean, I think we should remove `style="white-space: nowrap"` from parent div.  You dont' need reset `white-space` for divs.

Comment: Your point is very valid, but keep in mind that we don't know what is going on behind the scenes. It is possible that in the Live Environment there might be additional data loaded in the parent div that may require the `nowrap` property. As the question is purposefully focused on allowing the child elements to break text, I think it would be better to specifically target the child elements, instead of the parent. Does that make sense? :)

Comment: @WorkWe - your advice however is still quite valid depending on the situation, so I have added it with an edit. :)

Comment: Haha, hope it help for this question.

Answer (score 2):

Updated fiddle link. as said by shuvo, add white-space:normal to childern div

```
`https://jsfiddle.net/gopal280377/tdc300up/2/`
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try white-space to be normal in the child.As you want to break the line..

```
<p class="text-center" style="word-wrap: break-word;white-space: normal;">
    sssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss
      </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove wrong code of `div` parent:

```
<div overflow-x:auto; width="100%" style="white-space: nowrap">
 // Some thing
</div>
```

To:

```
<div width="100%" style="white-space: nowrap">
 // Some thing
</div>
```

Note: You can remove `width="100%"`, because `div`  block tag, width default is `100%`.

And reset `white-space` for `text-center` class is:

```
.text-center {
   white-space: normal;
}
```